# Convert the animation inside FBX into Unity

Tags: unity, animation, fbx

Recently i bought a package with an fbx and lots of animations.

Since I want full control and change a couple of details, I want to convert them into the regular Unities Animation System.
I cant convert them into the normal Unity Animations though.
They are "read only".

I can load them, copy paste them into my own "not-read-only" animation file.
But somehow i cant change the file anymore after I pasted something inside.

What am I doing wrong?
Is that something "impossible"?
Can you guys help?

Comment: AFAIK, You can't change the animation of an imported fbx file. You need to do this in a software like Maya or Blender.

Comment: what kind of change you want? do you want to short the clip?

Answer (score 2):

Allright, its a kind of a workaround but here is how it works:

1.
If your Animation inside the FBX is a Humanoid (Avatar/Mecanim..) Animation you have to convert it into a Legacy animation first.  Click on the file, import settings, pick animation, convert to legacy.

2.
Place a Animation-Compontent to you Animateable Gameobject and increase the Animation Size to 2. Insert your Legacy animation in, and insert a new empty animation in.

3.
In the Unity-Animator copy all read-only keyframes and paste them into your new empty animation.  You have to use: "ctrl+c / ctrl+v"

4.
Profit.
The empty Animation is changeable

Comment: If this solution worked for you, don't forget to mark it "Accepted"